# Calling a javascript function from a modal window in vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to calling a javascript function from a asp.net modal window using vb. The javascript function is to close the same modal window.

The function I want call is:  `function CloseModalWindow(winName)`

I tried

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
```

but that does not work.
How can I do that from vb.net code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually on the exact right track.

You should find that you are able to call the described method by using something like this...

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "window.parent.CloseModalWindow('WindowName');", True)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to close a modal window, perhaps place a label on the aspx side, and then  use a label with similar to:

```
<a href="javascript:CloseModalWindow('ThisWindow')"><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Close Me"></Label></a>
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using a web browser control and launching the page and function from that? Make the control not visible aswell.